# view SOAP request before it is sent to a web-service

Tags: .net, web-services

I am consuming a SOAP based web-service with .net 3.5
The web-service itself is developed in Java.

I know what the SOAP request *should* look like; And I am building the similar request in .net. However, I want to look at the XML that is sent to the web-service.

Is there a tool that would allow me to see what the request that I send look like just before it hits the web-service?

Comment: _How_ are you consuming the service? Are you using a Web Reference, or a Service Reference?

Comment: Too bad. If you were using a service reference, it would be trivial to trace the traffic. Instead, you should use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/).

Comment: Yes, I've been trying to figure out how to use Fiddler to see the entire request. All I am able to see is the request header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Apache tcpmon[1] to view the messages pass through.

[1] http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/